# Binance python API - ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 5 elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to get the daily data from all BUSD and USDT pairs from Binance over the past 2 years.

I have created 2 lists of BUSD and USDT pairs like this:
`busd_list = ["BTCBUSD","ETHBUSD","BNBBUSD"...]`

Then for each element of this list I want to execute the function below:

```
def klines_2_dataframe(ticker):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(ticker,"1d","1 Jan, 2020"))
    new_df = new_df.iloc[:,:5]
    new_df.columns = ['Time','open','high','low','close']
    new_df[["open","high","low","close"]] = new_df[["open","high","low","close"]].astype(float)
    new_df.Time = pd.to_datetime(new_df.Time,unit="ms")
    return new_df
```

And how I want to save those dataframe inside a SQLite database:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"busd_pairs.sqlite"))
for tickers in busd_symbols:
   df = klines_2_dataframe(tickers)
   df.to_sql(tickers,db,index=False,index_label=df.Time,if_exists='replace')
```

Weirdly when I execute this line alone:

`new_df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(ticker,"1d","1 Jan, 2020"))`

whatever the ticker value, there is no error.

But when I run it inside a loop I get this error over and over:
`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 5 elements`

It seems that it happens for lots of pairs, but I still don't get why.
It also seems to be an issue about the number of columns of my dataframe but I don't get why some are an issue and not other...

If anyone can help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Most probably your dataframe is empty (so 0 elements on the column axis), when you try to assign 5 new column names it crashes. Try to print the dataframe at each iteration to verify.

Comment: It displays the same error even when I pre-create a dataframe with 5 columns. It also displays this error when I get the first dataframe (with 12 columns) and I drop the columns I don't want...
I actually don't know which line precisely is creating this error.

Comment: @Shaido I still have the issue... i don't get why it works for some of them and not for other, do you have an idea ? (beside the empty dataframe because even though I create a dataframe with 5 columns before this bug still occurs..)